# MvvmCross - MonoTouch Target Binding for Layer.BackgroundColor

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using MvvmCross I have created the following target binding for `Layer.BackgroundColor` (in order to take advantage of `Layer.CornerRadius` for drawing a circle) but I (still) receive the error `Failed to create target binding for binding Layer.BackgroundColor for Color`.

#### MvxUIViewLayerBackgroundColorTargetBinding.cs

```
public class MvxUIViewLayerBackgroundColorTargetBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding {
    public MvxUIViewLayerBackgroundColorTargetBinding(object target) : base (target) {}

    public override Type TargetType {
        get { return typeof(CGColor); }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value) {
        var view = (UIView) target;

        if (view == null || value == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (view.Layer == null) {
            return;
        }

        view.Layer.BackgroundColor = ((UIColor) value).CGColor;
    }
}
```

#### In Setup.cs

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry) {
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UIView>("LayerBackgroundColor", view => new MvxUIViewLayerBackgroundColorTargetBinding(view));
}
```

#### The Binding

```
set.Bind(circle)
   .For(x => x.Layer.BackgroundColor)
   .To(x => x.Color)
   .WithConversion(new ColorNameToValueConverter(), null);
```

Comment: Looking at your binding it already does the 'layer' unwrapping - so maybe just try `.For("LayerBackgroundColor")`

Comment: Thanks, that works :-) Interesting though, I tried binding directly without the factory with a converter which returned `CGColor` and it didn't work :S

Comment: Binding "circle.layer" for "backgroundcolor" would probably have worked with the converter

Comment: That works/makes sense - can you post it as the answer so I can mark it as correct please? :-)